# Start external app with ShellExecuteEx and wait until it become initialized

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, shellexecuteex

I have an application which needs to run several other applications in chain. I am running them via `ShellExecuteEx`. The order of running each of the apps is very important cause they are dependant on each other. For example:

```
Start(App1);

If App1.IsRunning then
  Start(App2);
If App2.IsRunning then
  Start(App3);
.........................
If App(N-1).IsRunning then
  Start(App(N));
```

Everything works fine but there is a one possible problem:
`ShellExecuteEx` starts the application, and return almost immediately. The problem might arise when for example `App1` has started properly but has not finished some internal tasks, it is not yet ready to use. But `ShellExecuteEx` is already starting `App2` which depends on the `App1`, and `App2` won't start properly because it needs fully initialized `App1`.

Please note, that I don't want to wait for `App(N-1)` to finish and then start `AppN`.

I don't know if this is possible to solve with ShellExecuteEx, I've tried to use

```
SEInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;
```

but without any effect.

After starting the `AppN` application I have a handle to the process. If I assume that the application is initialized after its main window is created (all of Apps have a window), can I somehow put a hook on its message queue and wait until `WM_CREATE` appears or maybe `WM_ACTIVATE`? In pressence of such message my Application would know that it can move on.

It's just an idea. However, I don't know how to put such hook. So if you could help me in this or you have a better idea that would be great:)

Also, the solution must work on Windows XP and above.

Thanks for your time.

**Edited**

@Cosmic Prund: I don't understand why did you delete your answer? I might try your idea...

Comment: WaitForInputIdle(hProcess ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you need by calling [`WaitForInputIdle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on each process handle returned by `ShellExecute()`.

> Waits until the specified process has finished processing its initial input and is waiting for user input with no input pending, or until the time-out interval has elapsed.

Comment: David: This sounds to good to be true ;) But what actually means that "specified process has finished its initialization"?

Comment: +1, nice and simple. @Wodzu, just made a simple application with a 10 seconds dumb loop in `FormCreate`, `WaitForInputIdle()` returned as soon as the loop was over (and the main form shown).

Comment: Thanks @Cosmin, anyway it is a shame that you deleted your answer. i wanted to award it too :)

Comment: @Wodzu, bad answers need to be deleted. Upvotes is not a reason to keep them. My record is deleting an answer with +7 score :)

Comment: @Wodzu what it means is that the message loop has started has reached an idle state at least once. I don't know whether that will meet your needs or not but there's a good chance it will.

Comment: Some apps might start their idle processing a little before this, but this is an incredibly good tip to know!  Great stuff David!

Answer (score 4):

If your application has some custom initialization logic that doesn't run in UI thread then WaitForInputIdle might not help. In that case you need a mechanism to signal the previous app that you're done initializing.

For signaling you can use named pipes, sockets, some RPC mechanism or a simple file based lock.

Comment: Thanks Hasan, but I've said and definied what I mean by initialization, a quote from myself "I assume that the application is initialized after its main window is created (all of Apps have a window)"

Comment: Then WaitForInputIdle is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Interpocess Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684123%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to make your application communicate with (and wait for, if needed) each other, as long as you code both applications.