# Waiting for applications to finish loading

Tags: delphi, api, shellexecute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start external app with ShellExecuteEx and wait until it become initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547408/start-external-app-with-shellexecuteex-and-wait-until-it-become-initialized)

Is there some way of getting a Delphi app to wait for an external application to finish loading before it proceeds processing? I have an app that launches other apps by using ShellExecute (I have to use ShellExecute as I only have a filename and verb to work with, it launches the associated application as required), but I need my app to wait until the launched app has finished loading before it proceeds. For example, MS Word can take several seconds to load depending on installed plugins etc.

I've seen code to get the app to wait until the launched app has been closed down, but I only need to wait till it has finished loading completely.

Ideas appreciated.